# ELB cross-AZ balancing DNS resolution with Sticky sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am preparing for AWS certification and came across a question about ELB with sticky session enabled for instances in 2 AZs. The problem is that  requests from a software-based load tester in one of the AZs end up in the instances in that AZ only instead of being distributed across AZs. At the same time regular requests from customers are evenly distributed across AZs.
The correct answers to fix the load tester issue are:

- Forced the software-based load tester to re-resolve DNS before every
  request;
- Use third party load-testing service to send requests from
  globally distributed clients.

I'm not sure I can understand this scenario. What is the default behaviour of Route 53 when it comes to ELB IPs resolution? In any case, those DNS records have 60 seconds TTL. Isn't it redundant to re-resolve DNS on every request? Besides, DNS resolution is a responsibility of DNS service itself, not load-testing software, isn't it?
I can understand that requests from the same instance, with load testing software on it, will go to the same LBed EC2, but why does it have to be an instance in the same AZ? It can be achieved only by Geolocation- or Latency-based routing, but I can't find anything in the specs whether those are the default ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an ELB is in more than one availability zone, it always has more than one public IP address -- at least one per zone.

When you request these records in a DNS lookup, you get all of these records (assuming there are not very many) or a subset of them (if there are a large number, which would be the case in an active cluster with significant traffic) but they are unordered.

If the load testing software resolves the IP address of the endpoint and holds onto exactly one of the IP addresses -- as it a likely outcome -- then all of the traffic will go to one node of the balancer, which is in one zone, and will send traffic to instances in that zone.

But what about...

> **Cross-Zone Load Balancing**
>
> The nodes for your load balancer distribute requests from clients to registered targets. When cross-zone load balancing is enabled, each load balancer node distributes traffic across the registered targets in all enabled Availability Zones. When cross-zone load balancing is disabled, each load balancer node distributes traffic across the registered targets in its Availability Zone only.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html

If stickiness is configured, those sessions will initially land in one AZ and then stick to that AZ because they stick to the initial instance where they landed.  If cross-zone is enabled, the outcome is not quite as clear, but either balancer nodes may prefer instances in their own zone in that scenario (when first establishing stickiness), or this wasn't really the point of the question.  Stickiness requires coordination, and cross-AZ traffic takes a non-zero amount of time due to distance (typically <10 ms) but it would make sense for a balancer to prefer to select instances its local zone for sessions with no established affinity.

In fact, configuring the load test software to re-resolve the endpoint for *each* request is not really the focus of the solution -- the point is to ensure that (1) the load test software uses all of them and does not latch onto exactly one and (2) that if more addresses become available due to the balancer scaling out under load, that the load test software expands its pool of targets.

> In any case, those DNS records have 60 seconds TTL. Isn't it redundant to re-resolve DNS on every request?

The software may not see the TTL, may not honor the TTL and, as noted above, may stick to one answer even if multiple are available, because it only needs one in order to make the connection.  *Every* request is not strictly necessary, but it does solve the problem.

> Besides, DNS resolution is a responsibility of DNS service itself, not load-testing software, isn't it?

To "resolve DNS" in this context simply means to do a DNS lookup, whatever that means in the specific instance, whether using the OS's DNS resolver or making a direct query to a recursive DNS server.  When software establishes a connection to a hostname, it "resolves" (looks up) the associated IP address.

The other solution, *"use third party load-testing service to send requests from globally distributed clients,"* solves the problem by accident, since the distributed clients -- even if they stick to the first address they see -- are more likely to see all of the available addresses.  The "global" distribution aspect is a distraction.

ELB relies on random arrival of requests across its external-facing nodes as part of the balancing strategy.  Load testing software whose design overlooks this is not *properly* testing the ELB.  Both solutions mitigate the problem in different ways.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. "but it would make sense for a balancer to prefer to select instances its local zone for sessions with no established affinity" - on the one hand, yes, but on the other - it can make for a really unbalanced distribution if there is the traffic is mostly coming from a specific AZ.

Comment: About Cross-Zone balancing - I'm sure it's what's implied, because the question also says that a regular traffic from a segment of users is distributed evenly across two AZs. And it seems it's not quite clear why and how Route53+ELB are configured by default for AutoScaling. As you mentioned: "If cross-zone is enabled, the outcome is not quite as clear"

Comment: No... normal traffic tends to be evenly distributed *even without* cross-zone balancing because the requests are randomly arriving at the various balancer nodes due to the unordered nature of the DNS responses from Route 53.  Individual browsers tend to do the exact same thing described in the question -- resolve once, and stick to one IP address -- but since there are many browsers, the balancing effect occurs naturally.  ELB *depends in part on* the balancing effect of the unordered/round robin DNS records, which is why a load test tool that does not repeat the DNS lookup behaves this way.

Comment: Well, if the number of instances is the same in all AZs(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#cross-zone-load-balancing) ...which was the case in the question.

Comment: In any case, I think it's clear now. The default Route 53 strategy is probably Single which is based on round-robin. That IP can be cached in DNS cache in the OS or in the software itself(JVM seems to make use of DNS caching as well, for example).

Comment: Having said that, it would make more sense for Route 53 to use Multivalue answer routing policy which will return all 6 instances' IPs(max is 8) and then it would be up to OS to round robin them. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multivalue-versus-simple-policies/

Comment: Route 53 already returns multiple answers, as I've already pointed out... but it is *extremely* common for an application to resolve the name, once, take one address, and run with it, based on the old assumption that there was no need to refresh the DNS lookup -- which of course takes time and resources.  I've seen old production Java back-end services that will make API calls to the one single IP address they found the first time they resolved an API endpoint and stick with it forever until restarted.

Comment: Apparently the JVM can have its own independent notion of DNS TTLs. *"On some Java configurations, the JVM default TTL is set so that it will never refresh DNS entries until the JVM is restarted. Thus, if the IP address for an AWS resource changes while your application is still running, it won't be able to use that resource until you manually restart the JVM and the cached IP information is refreshed. In this case, it's crucial to set the JVM's TTL so that it will periodically refresh its cached IP information."* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html

Answer (score 2):

The sticky is the issue , see here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

> The load balancer uses a special cookie to associate the session with
>   the instance that handled the initial request, but follows the
>   lifetime of the application cookie specified in the policy
>   configuration. The load balancer only inserts a new stickiness cookie
>   if the application response includes a new application cookie. The
>   load balancer stickiness cookie does not update with each request. If
>   the application cookie is explicitly removed or expires, the session
>   stops being sticky until a new application cookie is issued.

The first solution, to re-resolve DNS will create new sessions and with this will break the stickiness of the ELB . The second solution is to use multiple clients , stickiness is not an issue if the number of globally distributed clients is large.

PART 2 : could not add as comment , is to long :

Yes, my answer was to simple and incomplete.

What we know is that ELB is 2 AZ and will have 2 nodes with different IP. Not clear how many IP , depends on the number of requests and the number of servers on each AZ. Route 53 is rotating the IP for every new request , first time in NodeA-IP , NodeB-IP , second time is NodeB-IP, NodeA-IP. The load testing application will take with every new request the first IP , balancing between the 2 AZ. Because a Node can route only inside his AZ , if the sticky cookie is for NodeA and the request arrives to NodeB , NodeB will send it to one of his servers in AZ2 ignoring the cookie for a server in AZ 1.

I need to run some tests, quickly tested with Route53 with classic ELB and 2 AZ and is rotating every time the IP's. What I want to test if I have a sticky cookie for AZ 1 and I reach the Node 2 will not forward me to Node 1 ( In case of no available servers, is described in the doc this interesting flow ). Hope to have updates in short time.

Comment: It's clear that the issue is about stickiness(even from the question in the test itself), but it's not a cookie from the application side in this case; DNS resolution in itself has nothing to do with sessions. The session is added as a Cookies(HTTP level), DNS is for Domain-to-IP mapping and has nothing to do with Cookies. Please, either provide more details/links or I will have to downvote your answer. Sorry.

Comment: Please check version 2 of my comment , sorry for being late

Comment: Thanks! It does answer some questions now. So, you are saying that by default Route 53 will return all ELB IPs(up to 8 I guess based on Route 53 limitations), but rotate them all the time? "Node can route only inside his AZ" - this is based on the assumption that cross-AZ feature is not enabled on the LB.

Answer (score 1):

Just found another piece of evidence that Route 53 returns multiple IPs and rotate them for ELB scaling scenarios:

> By default, Elastic Load Balancing will return multiple IP addresses when clients perform a DNS resolution, with the records being randomly ordered on each DNS resolution request. As the traffic profile changes, the controller service will scale the load balancers to handle more requests, scaling equally in all Availability Zones.

And then:

> To ensure that clients are taking advantage of the increased capacity, Elastic Load Balancing uses a TTL setting on the DNS record of 60 seconds. It is critical that you factor this changing DNS record into your tests. If you do not ensure that DNS is re-resolved or use multiple test clients to simulate increased load, the test may continue to hit a single IP address when Elastic Load Balancing has actually allocated many more IP addresses.

What I didn't realize at first is that even if regular traffic is distributed evenly across AZs, it doesn't mean that Cross-Zone Load Balancing is enabled. As Michael pointed out regular traffic will naturally come through various locations and end up in different AZs.
And as it was not explicitly mentioned in the test, Cross-AZ balancing might not have been in place.

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/best-practices-in-evaluating-elastic-load-balancing/